# Please Explain the Missing Lines of my Assembly Shellcode. What are the EXECVE Parameters?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, nasm, shellcode

I know what it does, but I'd really like an explaination why?

```
SECTION .data
        global _start
_start:
        jmp j ;jump to 'j' label
r:
        pop ebx ;Pop the address of 'shell' into EBX. Parameter is Filename
        xor eax, eax ; clear EAX register
        mov BYTE[ebx+7], al ;push one NUL byte to end any string reading
        mov DWORD[ebx+8], ebx ;mov address of EBX into the content EBX (offset of 8)
        mov DWORD[ebx+12], eax ;mov 4 NUL bytes at EBX (offset of 12)
        mov al, 11d ;execve system call
        lea ecx, [ebx+8] ; HELP
        lea edx, [ebx+12] ; HELP
        int 80h ;Kernel call
j:      call r ;call r... pushes 'shell' address onto the stack
shell:  db "/bin/sh" ;file name
```

Specifically, I'd like to know:
1) What are the 3 parameters of execve (I've looked at the `man 2 execve` and it's no help)
2) What EXACTLY does LEA do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments to `mov DWORD[ebx+8], ebx` and `mov DWORD[ebx+12], eax` are wrong, or at least misleading.

The bytes at label 'shell' are '/bin/sh', which makes 7 bytes, and `mov BYTE[ebx+7], al` terminates this string wih a null byte.

The next statement, `mov DWORD[ebx+8], ebx`, moves the content of ebx - which is a pointer to shell - to the 4 bytes behind shell.

After that, `mov DWORD[ebx+12], eax` moves a zero to the 4 next bytes. So we have the following memory layout, where `bxbxbxbx` is the address of the start of this memory block:

```
  bx                                 value=bx, points to /bin/sh
  |                                ___________
  v                               /           \
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| / | b | i | n | / | s | h |\0 |bx |bx |bx |bx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The two LEA instructions move the address of (bx+8) and (bx+12) to cx and dx, respectively. You could replace them with `MOV CX, BX; ADD CX, 8; MOV DX, BX; ADD DX,12`.

```
  bx
  |
  v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| / | b | i | n | / | s | h |\0 |bx |bx |bx |bx | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                  ^               ^
                                  cx              dx
```

Now if you look at execvp:

The first argument, in bx, is a pointer to a string containing the name of the file to execute. That's `/bin/sh`.
The second argument, in cx, is a pointer to an array of strings to pass to the program to be executed as argv. Here, this consists of a pointer to "/bin/sh", and a NULL pointer. The NULL pointer is used as array terminator (see execve docs), as there's no explicit array length.
The third argument, in dx, is the pointer to the environment for the new process - as it's a pointer to a NULL pointer, the new process doesn't inherit any environment variables from you.